# How can log4net be configured using a System.Configuration.Configuration

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have developed a library that is being consumed by an add-in architecture in another application. My library uses log4net for logging.

This works fine in testing as the location of the app.config can be resolved and log4net is configured using:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

When loaded as an add-in it isn't possible to resolve the application configuration using this method.

One option is to configure log4net using a Configuration that is passed in through the add-in architecture. The configuration that can be used is similar to the results of the following:

```
string asmFile = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
System.Configuration.Configuration dllConfig = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(asmFile);
```

How can the [System.Configuration.Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.aspx) be used with the [log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.html)?

I can see the applicable ConfigurationSection from the configuration but can't see a way to easily get the ILoggerRepository or XmlElement required by [XmlConfigurator.Configure()](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure_overloads.html).

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection configSection = configuration.GetSection("log4net");
```

Comment: Can't you add your config file to the map of the project using your library?

Comment: @Carra, could you elaborate? For this project I'm passing the library off to external developers to consume and integrate with the add-in architecture project. I have no control over how they consume it (other than the API I publish) but need to provide a method for them to configure it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best I've come up with to date and it doesn't seem particularly robust.

```
if (configuration.HasFile)
{
        System.IO.FileInfo configFileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(configuration.FilePath);
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(configFileInfo);
}
```

I did think about using an XmlSerializer writing the configuration to an XmlDocument and then passing that XmlElement into Configure but I couldn't get the configuration to serialize.

Answer (score 0):

> I have no control over how they
>   consume it (other than the API I
>   publish) but need to provide a method
>   for them to configure it.

Our log4net wrapper is in a dll. The projects that use this logging framework just have to add the log4net configuration block in the config file of their webservices/clients.

Besides that the programs have to call this at the startup:

```
    XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

Comment: Interesting, but unfortunately I can't config the logging as part of the core application as my library is loaded as a add-in. The configuration of my add-in, such as connection strings and app settings, must be independent from the core application.